# ARMA forecast has data forecast gap?

Tags: r, forecasting, arma

I am currently doing a project with R, and I am trying to forecast a dataset that starts in 1992,january and ends in 2015,december. The data has a monthly frequency.

I find that the best model to forecast is ARMA 5,3. I am using a model with trend and seasonal component to forecast. However, when i try to forecast the data, there is a gap between the last observation of the sample and the first observation of the forecast.

[image: Forecast]
Code is as follows for a 5 year forecast (60 months):

```
    h=60
    fz=((length(sales)+1):(length(sales)+h))

    FMo1 = rep(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo2 = rep(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo3 = rep(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)      
    FMo4 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo5 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo6 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo7 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo8 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo9 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo10 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), h/12)
    FMo11 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), h/12)
    FMo12 = rep(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), h/12)
    OutTrend = model.matrix(~ 0  +fz+FMo1+FMo2+FMo3+FMo4+FMo5+FMo6+FMo7+FMo8+FMo9+FMo10+FMo11+FMo12)

    Fitoutsample = sales-arma53.model$residuals


    Forecast1=predict(arma53.model,h,newxreg=OutTrend)$pred
    UF=predict(arma53.model,h,newxreg=OutTrend)$pred+1.96*predict(arma53.model,h,newxreg=OutTrend)$se
LF=predict(arma53.model,h,newxreg=OutTrend)$pred1.96*predict(arma53.model,h,newxreg=OutTrend)$se


    plot(sales,xlim=c(2010,2016+h/12),ylim=c(100000,500000),ylab="Retail sales",main="ARMA(5,3) model with trend and seasonality")
    lines(Fitoutsample,col="green")
    lines(Forecast1,col="blue")
    lines(UF,col="red")
    lines(LF,col="red")

    plot(sales,xlim=c(1992,2016+h/12),ylim=c(100000,500000),ylab="Retail    sales",main="ARMA(5,3) model with trend and seasonality")
    lines(Fitoutsample,col="green")
    lines(Forecast1,col="blue")
    lines(UF,col="red")
    lines(LF,col="red")
```

The problem also happens when i do an insample forecast, note the period by the end of 2014 that is not covered by the insample forecast:

[image]

Comment: No, there is not a gap there is a problem with the graph there is still underlying data. You might have to join it.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: I am a little confused ARMA(5,3)  has 5 autoregressive parameters and three moving average parameters.  This is a stationary model.  But you claim a trend and a seasonal component and your data suggests it.  How did you fit the Model?  Are you using the right notation to describe the model?

Comment: I am a student undergoing an elective in R language. 

The way the project works is I find a dataset that increases linearly and has a seasonal pattern, as in this case. I used a linear trend and a seasonal trend which had an adjusted R square of 99.7 and then i ran test of AR,MA and ARMA depending on my analysis of the ACF and PACF of residuals provided by the linear+seasonal trend. ARMA 5,3 had the lowest AIC and i used it for this forecast.

The forecast looks fine. I cross checked the first months of 2016 i forecast, and they have a 5-7 percent difference. But how do i fix that gap?

Comment: Perhaps your series has changes in trends or levels over time. Perhaps the seasonal factors have changed over time . perhaps the error process from your models suggests increased volatility i.e. increased or even decreased error variance. perhaps your parameters have changed over time ..Only the data knows for sure or maybe Lamont Cranston knows (joke) .. It is your job/mission to verify any and all of these things as they can have an impact on your prediction error.

Comment: I have also done an in-sample verification and the prediction model is fine. The gap is not a problem with the model, its a problem with the data and i don't know how to fix it? I uploaded the insample in the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* gap. Your data is discretely sampled, at monthly intervals. The forecasts are discrete, at monthly intervals. The lines in between these points are linear interpolations for the purpose of painting a pretty picture but they have no meaning. Try to plot with points (use the argument `type="b"` in the plot function) and you will see: the points are regularly spaced and there is no gap.

If you absolutely want there to be a line in between the last data point and the first forecasted point, duplicate the last data point at the beginning of your forecast vector. This will make it draw an extra line segment of the same color as your regular forecast.